# A problem on Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, ergodic-theory

Suppose, $\Pi_{\theta}$ be the transition probability function of a Markov chain. For any function $f$ define 
$$\Pi_{\theta}f_{\theta}(x) = \int f(y,\theta)\Pi_{\theta}(x,dy).$$

Is there any intuitive meaning of the function ?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\Pi_{\theta}f_{\theta}(x)$ is the expectation of the random variable $f(X_1,\theta)$ when $X_0=x$ almost surely and when $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain with transition kernel $\Pi_{\theta}$.